# PDF text alignment issue in iText

Tags: java, itext

Below is Java code, where I try to convert a HTML file into PDF using Java with iText.

```java
public static void generatePDFTestThree() {
    try {
         String dirPath="F:\\Nitin\\ppi\\GPR\\form_pdf";
        //Setting destination 
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(dirPath+"/PagePdf.html"));
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dirPath + "/PageHtmlToPdf.pdf"));
        
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(fileOutputStream);
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        converterProperties.setLimitOfLayouts(4);
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter);
        converterProperties.setBaseUri("src/resources/images");
        //For setting the PAGE SIZE
        pdfDocument.setDefaultPageSize(new PageSize(PageSize.LETTER));
        
        Document document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(fileInputStream, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
        document.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Below is my HTML file which I try to convert to PDF.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="generator" content="pdf2htmlEX"/>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
<style type="text/css">
#sidebar{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;width:250px;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:auto}#page-container{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;margin:0;padding:0;border:0}@media screen{#sidebar.opened+#page-container{left:250px}#page-container{bottom:0;right:0;overflow:auto}.loading-indicator{display:none}.loading-indicator.active{display:block;position:absolute;width:64px;height:64px;top:50%;left:50%;margin-top:-32px;margin-left:-32px}.loading-indicator img{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;bottom:0;right:0}}@media print{@page{margin:0}html{margin:0}body{text-align:left;margin:0;-webkit-print-color-adjust:exact}#sidebar{display:none}#page-container{width:auto;height:auto;overflow:visible;background-color:transparent}.d{display:none}}.pf{position:relative;background-color:white;overflow:hidden;margin:0;border:0}.pc{position:absolute;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;display:block;transform-origin:0 0;-ms-transform-origin:0 0;-webkit-transform-origin:0 0}.pc.opened{display:block}.bf{position:absolute;border:0;margin:0;top:0;bottom:0;width:100%;height:100%;-ms-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none}.bi{position:absolute;border:0;margin:0;-ms-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-webkit-user-select:none;user-select:none}@media print{.pf{margin:0;box-shadow:none;page-break-after:always;page-break-inside:avoid}#fff}.pc{overflow:visible}}}.c{position:absolute;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;overflow:hidden;display:block}.t{position:absolute;white-space:pre;font-size:1px;transform-origin:0 100%;-ms-transform-origin:0 100%;-webkit-transform-origin:0 100%;unicode-bidi:bidi-override;-moz-font-feature-settings:"liga" 0}.t:after{content:''}.t:before{content:''}.t span{position:relative;unicode-bidi:bidi-override}._{color:transparent;z-index:-1}::selection{background:rgba(127,255,255,0.4)}::-moz-selection{background:rgba(127,255,255,0.4)}.pi{display:none}.d{position:absolute;transform-origin:0 100%;-ms-transform-origin:0 100%;-webkit-transform-origin:0 100%}.it{border:0;background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.0)}.ir:hover{cursor:pointer}</style>
<style type="text/css">
/*! 
 * Fancy styles for pdf2htmlEX
 * Copyright 2012,2013 Lu Wang <coolwanglu@gmail.com> 
 * https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX/blob/master/share/LICENSE
 */@media screen{#sidebar{background-color:#2f3236;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI0IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjQiPgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI0IiBmaWxsPSIjNDAzYzNmIj48L3JlY3Q+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDBMNCA0Wk00IDBMMCA0WiIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIxIiBzdHJva2U9IiMxZTI5MmQiPjwvcGF0aD4KPC9zdmc+")}#outline{font-family:Georgia,Times,"Times New Roman",serif;font-size:13px;margin:2em 1em}#outline ul{padding:0}#outline li{list-style-type:none;margin:1em 0}#outline li>ul{margin-left:1em}#outline a,#outline a:visited,#outline a:hover,#outline a:active{line-height:1.2;color:#e8e8e8;text-overflow:ellipsis;white-space:nowrap;text-decoration:none;display:block;overflow:hidden;outline:0}#outline a:hover{color:#0cf}#page-container{background-color:#9e9e9e;background-image:url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSI1IiBoZWlnaHQ9IjUiPgo8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1IiBmaWxsPSIjOWU5ZTllIj48L3JlY3Q+CjxwYXRoIGQ9Ik0wIDVMNSAwWk02IDRMNCA2Wk0tMSAxTDEgLTFaIiBzdHJva2U9IiM4ODgiIHN0cm9rZS13aWR0aD0iMSI+PC9wYXRoPgo8L3N2Zz4=");-webkit-transition:left 500ms;transition:left 500ms}.pf{margin:13px auto;box-shadow:1px 1px 3px 1px #333;border-collapse:separate}.pc.opened{-webkit-animation:fadein 100ms;animation:fadein 100ms}.loading-indicator.active{-webkit-animation:swing 1.5s ease-in-out .01s infinite alternate none;animation:swing 1.5s ease-in-out .01s infinite alternate none}.checked{background:no-repeat url(data:image/png;base64,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)}}</style>
<style type="text/css">
.ff0{font-family:sans-serif;visibility:hidden;}
.ff3{font-family:ff3;line-height:1.037000;font-style:normal;font-weight:normal;visibility:visible;}
.m1{transform:matrix(0.237173,0.000000,-0.079050,0.237173,0,0);-ms-transform:matrix(0.237173,0.000000,-0.079050,0.237173,0,0);-webkit-transform:matrix(0.237173,0.000000,-0.079050,0.237173,0,0);}
.m0{transform:matrix(0.250000,0.000000,0.000000,0.250000,0,0);-ms-transform:matrix(0.250000,0.000000,0.000000,0.250000,0,0);-webkit-transform:matrix(0.250000,0.000000,0.000000,0.250000,0,0);}
.v0{vertical-align:0.000000px;}
.ls2{letter-spacing:0.000000px;}
.ls1{letter-spacing:0.144000px;}
.ls0{letter-spacing:0.376320px;}
.sc_{text-shadow:none;}
.sc1{text-shadow:-0.015em 0 transparent,0 0.015em transparent,0.015em 0 transparent,0 -0.015em  transparent;}
.sc0{text-shadow:-0.015em 0 rgb(36,63,144),0 0.015em rgb(36,63,144),0.015em 0 rgb(36,63,144),0 -0.015em  rgb(36,63,144);}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
.sc_{-webkit-text-stroke:0px transparent;}
.sc1{-webkit-text-stroke:0.015em transparent;text-shadow:none;}
.sc0{-webkit-text-stroke:0.015em rgb(36,63,144);text-shadow:none;}
}
.ws1{word-spacing:-9.600000px;}
.ws0{word-spacing:-7.968000px;}
.ws2{word-spacing:0.000000px;}
._b{margin-left:-6.208000px;}
._8{margin-left:-4.408000px;}
._3{margin-left:-1.067040px;}
._7{width:1.160000px;}
._c{width:21.224000px;}
._4{width:23.032000px;}
._e{width:32.640000px;}
._9{width:35.432000px;}
._f{width:41.816000px;}
._d{width:47.416000px;}
._11{width:49.784000px;}
._10{width:61.376000px;}
._12{width:104.600000px;}
._6{width:110.936000px;}
._a{width:127.184000px;}
._5{width:134.400000px;}
._0{width:514.392000px;}
._1{width:751.592000px;}
._2{width:1934.320000px;}
.fc3{color:transparent;}
.fc2{color:rgb(30,30,30);}
.fc1{color:rgb(0,0,0);}
.fc0{color:rgb(36,63,144);}
.fs4{font-size:20.160000px;}
.fs1{font-size:32.160000px;}
.fs5{font-size:33.899278px;}
.fs0{font-size:39.840000px;}
.fs2{font-size:48.000000px;}
.fs3{font-size:56.160000px;}
.y0{bottom:-0.500000px;}
.y1{bottom:0.000000px;}
.y4{bottom:40.320000px;}
.y24{bottom:52.320000px;}
.y22{bottom:80.280000px;}
.y21{bottom:104.900000px;}
.y20{bottom:129.500000px;}
.y1f{bottom:154.100000px;}
.y1e{bottom:175.460000px;}
.y1d{bottom:193.100000px;}
.y1c{bottom:214.460000px;}
.y1b{bottom:235.100000px;}
.y1a{bottom:259.700000px;}
.y19{bottom:284.330000px;}
.y18{bottom:308.930000px;}
.y17{bottom:333.530000px;}
.y16{bottom:358.130000px;}
.y15{bottom:382.730000px;}
.y14{bottom:407.330000px;}
.y13{bottom:431.950000px;}
.y12{bottom:456.550000px;}
.y11{bottom:481.150000px;}
.y10{bottom:505.750000px;}
.yf{bottom:530.350000px;}
.ye{bottom:554.950000px;}
.yd{bottom:579.550000px;}
.y23{bottom:595.180000px;}
.yc{bottom:604.180000px;}
.yb{bottom:628.780000px;}
.ya{bottom:653.380000px;}
.y9{bottom:677.980000px;}
.y8{bottom:702.580000px;}
.y7{bottom:721.540000px;}
.y6{bottom:733.420000px;}
.y5{bottom:752.860000px;}
.y3{bottom:773.400000px;}
.y2{bottom:783.480000px;}
.h7{height:16.894080px;}
.h3{height:27.432480px;}
.h8{height:29.390674px;}
.h2{height:33.983520px;}
.h6{height:40.224000px;}
.h4{height:41.616000px;}
.h5{height:47.062080px;}
.h9{height:112.800000px;}
.h0{height:841.920000px;}
.h1{height:842.500000px;}
.w3{width:120.020000px;}
.w2{width:595.319991px;}
.w0{width:595.320000px;}
.w1{width:596.000000px;}
.x0{left:0.000000px;}
.x5{left:17.760000px;}
.x2{left:53.999991px;}
.x1{left:157.459991px;}
.x3{left:212.209991px;}
.x4{left:435.100000px;}
@media print{
.v0{vertical-align:0.000000pt;}
.ls2{letter-spacing:0.000000pt;}
.ls1{letter-spacing:0.192000pt;}
.ls0{letter-spacing:0.501760pt;}
.ws1{word-spacing:-12.800000pt;}
.ws0{word-spacing:-10.624000pt;}
.ws2{word-spacing:0.000000pt;}
._b{margin-left:-8.277333pt;}
._8{margin-left:-5.877333pt;}
._3{margin-left:-1.422720pt;}
._7{width:1.546667pt;}
._c{width:28.298667pt;}
._4{width:30.709333pt;}
._e{width:43.520000pt;}
._9{width:47.242667pt;}
._f{width:55.754667pt;}
._d{width:63.221333pt;}
._11{width:66.378667pt;}
._10{width:81.834667pt;}
._12{width:139.466667pt;}
._6{width:147.914667pt;}
._a{width:169.578667pt;}
._5{width:179.200000pt;}
._0{width:685.856000pt;}
._1{width:1002.122667pt;}
._2{width:2579.093333pt;}
.fs4{font-size:26.880000pt;}
.fs1{font-size:42.880000pt;}
.fs5{font-size:45.199037pt;}
.fs0{font-size:53.120000pt;}
.fs2{font-size:64.000000pt;}
.fs3{font-size:74.880000pt;}
.y0{bottom:-0.666667pt;}
.y1{bottom:0.000000pt;}
.y4{bottom:53.760000pt;}
.y24{bottom:69.760000pt;}
.y22{bottom:107.040000pt;}
.y21{bottom:139.866667pt;}
.y20{bottom:172.666667pt;}
.y1f{bottom:205.466667pt;}
.y1e{bottom:233.946667pt;}
.y1d{bottom:257.466667pt;}
.y1c{bottom:285.946667pt;}
.y1b{bottom:313.466667pt;}
.y1a{bottom:346.266667pt;}
.y19{bottom:379.106667pt;}
.y18{bottom:411.906667pt;}
.y17{bottom:444.706667pt;}
.y16{bottom:477.506667pt;}
.y15{bottom:510.306667pt;}
.y14{bottom:543.106667pt;}
.y13{bottom:575.933333pt;}
.y12{bottom:608.733333pt;}
.y11{bottom:641.533333pt;}
.y10{bottom:674.333333pt;}
.yf{bottom:707.133333pt;}
.ye{bottom:739.933333pt;}
.yd{bottom:772.733333pt;}
.y23{bottom:793.573333pt;}
.yc{bottom:805.573333pt;}
.yb{bottom:838.373333pt;}
.ya{bottom:871.173333pt;}
.y9{bottom:903.973333pt;}
.y8{bottom:936.773333pt;}
.y7{bottom:962.053333pt;}
.y6{bottom:977.893333pt;}
.y5{bottom:1003.813333pt;}
.y3{bottom:1031.200000pt;}
.y2{bottom:1044.640000pt;}
.h7{height:22.525440pt;}
.h3{height:36.576640pt;}
.h8{height:39.187565pt;}
.h2{height:45.311360pt;}
.h6{height:53.632000pt;}
.h4{height:55.488000pt;}
.h5{height:62.749440pt;}
.h9{height:150.400000pt;}
.h0{height:1122.560000pt;}
.h1{height:1123.333333pt;}
.w3{width:160.026667pt;}
.w2{width:793.759988pt;}
.w0{width:793.760000pt;}
.w1{width:794.666667pt;}
.x0{left:0.000000pt;}
.x5{left:23.680000pt;}
.x2{left:71.999988pt;}
.x1{left:209.946655pt;}
.x3{left:282.946655pt;}
.x4{left:580.133333pt;}
}
</style>
<script>
/*
 Copyright 2012 Mozilla Foundation 
 Copyright 2013 Lu Wang <coolwanglu@gmail.com>
 Apachine License Version 2.0 
*/
(function(){function b(a,b,e,f){var c=(a.className||"").split(/\s+/g);""===c[0]&&c.shift();var d=c.indexOf(b);0>d&&e&&c.push(b);0<=d&&f&&c.splice(d,1);a.className=c.join(" ");return 0<=d}if(!("classList"in document.createElement("div"))){var e={add:function(a){b(this.element,a,!0,!1)},contains:function(a){return b(this.element,a,!1,!1)},remove:function(a){b(this.element,a,!1,!0)},toggle:function(a){b(this.element,a,!0,!0)}};Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype,"classList",{get:function(){if(this._classList)return this._classList;
var a=Object.create(e,{element:{value:this,writable:!1,enumerable:!0}});Object.defineProperty(this,"_classList",{value:a,writable:!1,enumerable:!1});return a},enumerable:!0})}})();
</script>
<script>
(function(){/*
 pdf2htmlEX.js: Core UI functions for pdf2htmlEX 
 Copyright 2012,2013 Lu Wang <coolwanglu@gmail.com> and other contributors 
 https://github.com/pdf2htmlEX/pdf2htmlEX/blob/master/share/LICENSE 
*/
{page_frame:"pf",page_content_box:"pc",page_data:"pi",background_image:"bi",link:"l",input_radio:"ir",__dummy__:"no comma"},DEFAULT_CONFIG={container_id:"page-container",sidebar_id:"sidebar",outline_id:"outline",loading_indicator_cls:"loading-indicator",preload_pages:3,render_timeout:100,scale_step:0.9,key_handler:!0,hashchange_handler:!0,view_history_handler:!0,__dummy__:"no comma"},EPS=1E-6;
function invert(a){var b=a[0]*a[3]-a[1]*a[2];return[a[3]/b,-a[1]/b,-a[2]/b,a[0]/b,(a[2]*a[5]-a[3]*a[4])/b,(a[1]*a[4]-a[0]*a[5])/b]}function transform(a,b){return[a[0]*b[0]+a[2]*b[1]+a[4],a[1]*b[0]+a[3]*b[1]+a[5]]}function get_page_number(a){return parseInt(a.getAttribute("data-page-no"),16)}function disable_dragstart(a){for(var b=0,c=a.length;b<c;++b)a[b].addEventListener("dragstart",function(){return!1},!1)}
function clone_and_extend_objs(a){for(var b={},c=0,e=arguments.length;c<e;++c){var h=arguments[c],d;for(d in h)h.hasOwnProperty(d)&&(b[d]=h[d])}return b}
function Page(a){if(a){this.shown=this.loaded=!1;this.page=a;this.num=get_page_number(a);this.original_height=a.clientHeight;this.original_width=a.clientWidth;var b=a.getElementsByClassName(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.page_content_box)[0];b&&(this.content_box=b,this.original_scale=this.cur_scale=this.original_height/b.clientHeight,this.page_data=JSON.parse(a.getElementsByClassName(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.page_data)[0].getAttribute("data-data")),this.ctm=this.page_data.ctm,this.ictm=invert(this.ctm),this.loaded=!0)}}
Page.prototype={hide:function(){this.loaded&&this.shown&&(this.content_box.classList.remove("opened"),this.shown=!1)},show:function(){this.loaded&&!this.shown&&(this.content_box.classList.add("opened"),this.shown=!0)},rescale:function(a){this.cur_scale=0===a?this.original_scale:a;this.loaded&&(a=this.content_box.style,a.msTransform=a.webkitTransform=a.transform="scale("+this.cur_scale.toFixed(3)+")");a=this.page.style;a.height=this.original_height*this.cur_scale+"px";a.width=this.original_width*this.cur_scale+
"px"},view_position:function(){var a=this.page,b=a.parentNode;return[b.scrollLeft-a.offsetLeft-a.clientLeft,b.scrollTop-a.offsetTop-a.clientTop]},height:function(){return this.page.clientHeight},width:function(){return this.page.clientWidth}};function Viewer(a){this.config=clone_and_extend_objs(DEFAULT_CONFIG,0<arguments.length?a:{});this.pages_loading=[];this.init_before_loading_content();var b=this;document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){b.init_after_loading_content()},!1)}
Viewer.prototype={scale:1,cur_page_idx:0,first_page_idx:0,init_before_loading_content:function(){this.pre_hide_pages()},initialize_radio_button:function(){for(var a=document.getElementsByClassName(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.input_radio),b=0;b<a.length;b++)a[b].addEventListener("click",function(){this.classList.toggle("checked")})},init_after_loading_content:function(){this.sidebar=document.getElementById(this.config.sidebar_id);this.outline=document.getElementById(this.config.outline_id);this.container=document.getElementById(this.config.container_id);
this.loading_indicator=document.getElementsByClassName(this.config.loading_indicator_cls)[0];for(var a=!0,b=this.outline.childNodes,c=0,e=b.length;c<e;++c)if("ul"===b[c].nodeName.toLowerCase()){a=!1;break}a||this.sidebar.classList.add("opened");this.find_pages();if(0!=this.pages.length){disable_dragstart(document.getElementsByClassName(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.background_image));this.config.key_handler&&this.register_key_handler();var h=this;this.config.hashchange_handler&&window.addEventListener("hashchange",
function(a){h.navigate_to_dest(document.location.hash.substring(1))},!1);this.config.view_history_handler&&window.addEventListener("popstate",function(a){a.state&&h.navigate_to_dest(a.state)},!1);this.container.addEventListener("scroll",function(){h.update_page_idx();h.schedule_render(!0)},!1);[this.container,this.outline].forEach(function(a){a.addEventListener("click",h.link_handler.bind(h),!1)});this.initialize_radio_button();this.render()}},find_pages:function(){for(var a=[],b={},c=this.container.childNodes,
e=0,h=c.length;e<h;++e){var d=c[e];d.nodeType===Node.ELEMENT_NODE&&d.classList.contains(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.page_frame)&&(d=new Page(d),a.push(d),b[d.num]=a.length-1)}this.pages=a;this.page_map=b},load_page:function(a,b,c){var e=this.pages;if(!(a>=e.length||(e=e[a],e.loaded||this.pages_loading[a]))){var e=e.page,h=e.getAttribute("data-page-url");if(h){this.pages_loading[a]=!0;var d=e.getElementsByClassName(this.config.loading_indicator_cls)[0];"undefined"===typeof d&&(d=this.loading_indicator.cloneNode(!0),
d.classList.add("active"),e.appendChild(d));var f=this,g=new XMLHttpRequest;g.open("GET",h,!0);g.onload=function(){if(200===g.status||0===g.status){var b=document.createElement("div");b.innerHTML=g.responseText;for(var d=null,b=b.childNodes,e=0,h=b.length;e<h;++e){var p=b[e];if(p.nodeType===Node.ELEMENT_NODE&&p.classList.contains(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.page_frame)){d=p;break}}b=f.pages[a];f.container.replaceChild(d,b.page);b=new Page(d);f.pages[a]=b;b.hide();b.rescale(f.scale);disable_dragstart(d.getElementsByClassName(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.background_image));
f.schedule_render(!1);c&&c(b)}delete f.pages_loading[a]};g.send(null)}void 0===b&&(b=this.config.preload_pages);0<--b&&(f=this,setTimeout(function(){f.load_page(a+1,b)},0))}},pre_hide_pages:function(){var a="@media screen{."+CSS_CLASS_NAMES.page_content_box+"{display:none;}}",b=document.createElement("style");b.styleSheet?b.styleSheet.cssText=a:b.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a));document.head.appendChild(b)},render:function(){for(var a=this.container,b=a.scrollTop,c=a.clientHeight,a=b-c,b=
b+c+c,c=this.pages,e=0,h=c.length;e<h;++e){var d=c[e],f=d.page,g=f.offsetTop+f.clientTop,f=g+f.clientHeight;g<=b&&f>=a?d.loaded?d.show():this.load_page(e):d.hide()}},update_page_idx:function(){var a=this.pages,b=a.length;if(!(2>b)){for(var c=this.container,e=c.scrollTop,c=e+c.clientHeight,h=-1,d=b,f=d-h;1<f;){var g=h+Math.floor(f/2),f=a[g].page;f.offsetTop+f.clientTop+f.clientHeight>=e?d=g:h=g;f=d-h}this.first_page_idx=d;for(var g=h=this.cur_page_idx,k=0;d<b;++d){var f=a[d].page,l=f.offsetTop+f.clientTop,
f=f.clientHeight;if(l>c)break;f=(Math.min(c,l+f)-Math.max(e,l))/f;if(d===h&&Math.abs(f-1)<=EPS){g=h;break}f>k&&(k=f,g=d)}this.cur_page_idx=g}},schedule_render:function(a){if(void 0!==this.render_timer){if(!a)return;clearTimeout(this.render_timer)}var b=this;this.render_timer=setTimeout(function(){delete b.render_timer;b.render()},this.config.render_timeout)},register_key_handler:function(){var a=this;window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll",function(b){if(b.ctrlKey){b.preventDefault();var c=a.container,
e=c.getBoundingClientRect(),c=[b.clientX-e.left-c.clientLeft,b.clientY-e.top-c.clientTop];a.rescale(Math.pow(a.config.scale_step,b.detail),!0,c)}},!1);window.addEventListener("keydown",function(b){var c=!1,e=b.ctrlKey||b.metaKey,h=b.altKey;switch(b.keyCode){case 61:case 107:case 187:e&&(a.rescale(1/a.config.scale_step,!0),c=!0);break;case 173:case 109:case 189:e&&(a.rescale(a.config.scale_step,!0),c=!0);break;case 48:e&&(a.rescale(0,!1),c=!0);break;case 33:h?a.scroll_to(a.cur_page_idx-1):a.container.scrollTop-=
a.container.clientHeight;c=!0;break;case 34:h?a.scroll_to(a.cur_page_idx+1):a.container.scrollTop+=a.container.clientHeight;c=!0;break;case 35:a.container.scrollTop=a.container.scrollHeight;c=!0;break;case 36:a.container.scrollTop=0,c=!0}c&&b.preventDefault()},!1)},rescale:function(a,b,c){var e=this.scale;this.scale=a=0===a?1:b?e*a:a;c||(c=[0,0]);b=this.container;c[0]+=b.scrollLeft;c[1]+=b.scrollTop;for(var h=this.pages,d=h.length,f=this.first_page_idx;f<d;++f){var g=h[f].page;if(g.offsetTop+g.clientTop>=
c[1])break}g=f-1;0>g&&(g=0);var g=h[g].page,k=g.clientWidth,f=g.clientHeight,l=g.offsetLeft+g.clientLeft,m=c[0]-l;0>m?m=0:m>k&&(m=k);k=g.offsetTop+g.clientTop;c=c[1]-k;0>c?c=0:c>f&&(c=f);for(f=0;f<d;++f)h[f].rescale(a);b.scrollLeft+=m/e*a+g.offsetLeft+g.clientLeft-m-l;b.scrollTop+=c/e*a+g.offsetTop+g.clientTop-c-k;this.schedule_render(!0)},fit_width:function(){var a=this.cur_page_idx;this.rescale(this.container.clientWidth/this.pages[a].width(),!0);this.scroll_to(a)},fit_height:function(){var a=this.cur_page_idx;
this.rescale(this.container.clientHeight/this.pages[a].height(),!0);this.scroll_to(a)},get_containing_page:function(a){for(;a;){if(a.nodeType===Node.ELEMENT_NODE&&a.classList.contains(CSS_CLASS_NAMES.page_frame)){a=get_page_number(a);var b=this.page_map;return a in b?this.pages[b[a]]:null}a=a.parentNode}return null},link_handler:function(a){var b=a.target,c=b.getAttribute("data-dest-detail");if(c){if(this.config.view_history_handler)try{var e=this.get_current_view_hash();window.history.replaceState(e,
"","#"+e);window.history.pushState(c,"","#"+c)}catch(h){}this.navigate_to_dest(c,this.get_containing_page(b));a.preventDefault()}},navigate_to_dest:function(a,b){try{var c=JSON.parse(a)}catch(e){return}if(c instanceof Array){var h=c[0],d=this.page_map;if(h in d){for(var f=d[h],h=this.pages[f],d=2,g=c.length;d<g;++d){var k=c[d];if(null!==k&&"number"!==typeof k)return}for(;6>c.length;)c.push(null);var g=b||this.pages[this.cur_page_idx],d=g.view_position(),d=transform(g.ictm,[d[0],g.height()-d[1]]),
g=this.scale,l=[0,0],m=!0,k=!1,n=this.scale;switch(c[1]){case "XYZ":l=[null===c[2]?d[0]:c[2]*n,null===c[3]?d[1]:c[3]*n];g=c[4];if(null===g||0===g)g=this.scale;k=!0;break;case "Fit":case "FitB":l=[0,0];k=!0;break;case "FitH":case "FitBH":l=[0,null===c[2]?d[1]:c[2]*n];k=!0;break;case "FitV":case "FitBV":l=[null===c[2]?d[0]:c[2]*n,0];k=!0;break;case "FitR":l=[c[2]*n,c[5]*n],m=!1,k=!0}if(k){this.rescale(g,!1);var p=this,c=function(a){l=transform(a.ctm,l);m&&(l[1]=a.height()-l[1]);p.scroll_to(f,l)};h.loaded?
c(h):(this.load_page(f,void 0,c),this.scroll_to(f))}}}},scroll_to:function(a,b){var c=this.pages;if(!(0>a||a>=c.length)){c=c[a].view_position();void 0===b&&(b=[0,0]);var e=this.container;e.scrollLeft+=b[0]-c[0];e.scrollTop+=b[1]-c[1]}},get_current_view_hash:function(){var a=[],b=this.pages[this.cur_page_idx];a.push(b.num);a.push("XYZ");var c=b.view_position(),c=transform(b.ictm,[c[0],b.height()-c[1]]);a.push(c[0]/this.scale);a.push(c[1]/this.scale);a.push(this.scale);return JSON.stringify(a)}};
pdf2htmlEX.Viewer=Viewer;})();
</script>
<script>
try{
pdf2htmlEX.defaultViewer = new pdf2htmlEX.Viewer({});
}catch(e){}
</script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sidebar">
<div id="outline">
</div>
</div>
<div id="page-container">
<div class="c x0 y1 w2 h0"><div class="t m0 x1 h2 y2 ff1 fs0 fc0 sc0 ls2 ws2"> <span class="_ _0"> </span> <span class="_ _1"> </span><span class="sc1">Page </span><span class="ls0">1</span><span class="sc1"> of </span><span class="ws0">1</span><span class="fs1 sc1"> </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h3 y3 ff1 fs1 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2"> </div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 y4 ff2 fs2 fc1 sc1 ls2 ws2"> <span class="_ _2"> </span> </div><div class="t m0 x3 h5 y5 ff3 fs3 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Customer Applicat<span class="_ _3"></span>ion Form </div><div class="t m0 x2 h6 y6 ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2"> </div><div class="t m0 x2 h7 y7 ff3 fs4 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2"> </div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 y8 ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Product Name*: <span class="ff2 fc1">Euronet Gift </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 y9 ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Application No.*: <span class="ff2 fc1">EN0000112233 </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 ya ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Customer Reference Number/ID*: <span class="ff2 fc1">1234567890 <span class="_ _4"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span><span class="fc3 sc1"> </span><span class="_ _5"> </span><span class="fc3 sc1"> </span></span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 yb ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Card Personalization*: <span class="ff2 fc1">Personalized </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 yc ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Card Number*: <span class="ff2 fc1 ws1">1234-56xx-<span class="ls1">xxxx</span><span class="ws2">-1234 </span></span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 yd ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Insta Card Reference/Kit Number*: <span class="ff2 fc1">INST0000112233 </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 ye ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">KYC Status*: <span class="ff2 fc1">Full KYC <span class="_ _6"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 yf ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">KYC Verification Date &amp; Time*<span class="_ _7"></span>: <span class="ff2 fc1">31/01/2023 13:00:00 </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 y10 ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Full Name*: <span class="ff2 fc1">Mr. Rashid Abdul Khan <span class="_ _8"></span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span><span class="ff3 fc0">Date of Birth*: </span>31/01/1990 </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 y11 ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Mobile Number*: <span class="ff2 fc1">+91-9891231231 <span class="_ _9"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span> <span class="_ _5"> </span></span>Email ID: <span class="ff2 fc1">rakhan90@rediffmail.com </span></div><div class="t m0 x2 h4 y12 ff3 fs2 fc0 sc1 ls2 ws2">Gender*: <span class="ff2 fc1">Male 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm getting following output PDF with right alignment text, which should be left align.

[image: Below is the pdf output:]

I'm also getting following warning/errors in console:

```
Unable to retrieve font:
 @font-face {
    font-family: ff1;
    src: url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAACV8AA8AAAAAWxgAAQ...

10:22:13.682 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - Unable to retrieve font:
 @font-face {
    font-family: ff2;
    src: url('data:application/font-woff;base64,d09GRgABAAAAAEcYAA8AAAAAl9wAAQGY..

[main] ERROR com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - No worker found for tag script
10:22:13.854 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - No worker found for tag script
10:22:13.854 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor - No worker found for tag script
10:22:14.135 [main] ERROR com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.AbstractRenderer - Occupied area has not been initialized. Absolute positioning might be applied incorrectly.
10:22:14.182 [main] WARN com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer - Inline block element does not fit into parent element and will be clipped
10:22:14.182 [main] WARN com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer - Inline block element does not fit into parent element and will be clipped
10:22:14.198 [main] WARN com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer - Inline block element does not fit into parent element and will be clipped
generatePDFTestThree Completed
```

I tried to set text alignment using below line in Java:

```java
Document document = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(fileInputStream, pdfDocument, converterProperties);
document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
```

However, this does not change the output. Please suggest the changes required to make this work.